# SpringBoot cron stopped firing in production EC2 instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a spring boot app which has a method running start of every hour with scheduled annotation. This has been running fine in AWS for more than a year until yesterday I found hourly cron stopped firing(no app logs) in Aug this year.
`@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 13-23 * * *")`
I have few other Spring boot(same version as above) apps in production with different cron schedule and they have been working fine so far. The only difference been they have been redeployed for changes in last one year.
At this time, I'm going thru Spring documentation but with little clue what can be wrong.
I'm looking for suggestions for debugging, link to spring cron detail understanding, honestly anything which can be of help.
We run Amzn Linux on our EC2s.

Comment: Are you using tomcat directly or docker?

Comment: @MohamedSweelam tomcat  and this is the only app running on this tomcat . One instance , one tomcat and one app.

Comment: You can expose a service to same cron, and add logs for simple tracing; then call this service directly.

Comment: May be your EC2 Instance has been relaunched on new zone or configured to be on different time. Try to use `zone` in your @Scheduled annotation like `@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 13-23 * * *", zone = "Europe/Berlin")`. I hope [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiCjQkM06U) on cron with zone would help.

Comment: Not sure of that @HarishVijayamohan since my stack is in one region only. Timezone doesn't change in one AWS region.